# data structure in a simple react app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building a react app, but stumbled over how to extract values from an array so that each item can be styled individually later.

Here is the situation,
There is an array of object in javascript:

```
let array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: -1}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: -2}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9, d: -3}]
```

I want to map through the array, so that I can extract certain values from each object in the array.

```
array.map((object) => {
  return <li>{object.a}{object.b}{object.d}</li>
})
```

What I got is:

- 1 2 -1
- 4 5 -2
- 7 8 -3

I can't easily style individual item in one line. What I want as result is:

- 1
- 2
- -1
- 4
- 5
- -2
  ...

How should I map through the array of object, so that it will output each item in their own

tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using latest react version (16+), then you can write it like this by using [**React.Fragment**](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
array.map((object, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={i}> 
        <li>{object.a}</li>
        <li>{object.b}</li>
        <li>{object.d}</li>
    </React.Fragment> 
))
```

For react version < 16 (this approach will work for 16+ also), write it like this:

```
array.map((object, i) => (
    [ 
        <li key={i}>{object.a}</li>,
        <li key={i+1}>{object.b}</li>,
        <li key={i+2}>{object.d}</li>,
    ]
))
```

**Note:** I used the index as key, make sure to use proper keys in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

```
array.map((object) => {
  return <li>{object.a}</li><li>{object.b}</li><li>{object.d}</li>
})
```

Comment: A JSX expression must have exactly 1 parent node,

Comment: oh, ok. my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

```
// ES6 

const list = number => `<li> ${number} </li>`;
const mapObject = ({ a, b, d }) => [a, b, d].map(x => list(x))
const reduceList = (acc, next) => acc.concat(next);

array
  .map(mapObject)
  .reduce(reduceList, []);

// ONE LINER
array
  .map(({ a, b, d }) => [a, b, d].map(x => `<li> ${x} </li>`))
  .reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(next), []);
```